# Обновление материализованного представления с помощью метода FAST

Tags: sql, oracle

Здравствуйте, есть необходимость использовать мат представление для сбора данных из таблицы в другой базе. Было принято решение использовать метод FAST так как он не обновляет таблицу полностью, а только изменения. Но так как исторические данные и вообще внесённые ранее могут быть изменены, появилось сомнение. Обновляет ли мат представление с методом обновления FAST старые данные, или же только вносит новые?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle накатывает инкрементальные изменения на `MV` (`Materialized View`) из MV Log. Соответственно все вектора изменений базовых таблиц (найденные в MV Log) будут применены к соответствующим MVs.

Comment: MaxU на сколько я понял, нужно создавать mv log, а как и по каким правилам она создаётся? Я ведь должен её сам создавать до создания мат представления.

Comment: @Андрей, [вот пример](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_6002.htm#i2106785)

Comment: MaxU, благодарю, если что то не понятно будет тогда спрогу в этой теме.

Comment: MaxU, а подскажите пожалуйста, если у меня запрос идёт к таблице которая находится в другой базе, но тоже орокловой, то есть через дибилинк, и я делаю мат вьюху для этого запроса, она будет обновлятся методом FAST? Или через дибилинк этот метод не действует и она будет обновлятся комплитом независимо от того что я ей выставил? Или это только на случай если дибилинк к другой базе не оракловой?

Comment: @Андрей, не знаю - надо пробовать